# check/uncheck Checkboxes in gridview while binding source

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I am working on a project.I have a gridview with one column having checkbox.Now I want to populate my gridview with data and check/uncheck checkboxes accordingly depending on my status field.Till now i am handling that in gridview row databound event.But I just want to know is there any way to mark the checkboxes while binding the source.

Query i am executing to get data in gridview

```
select s.studentcode,s.studentname,r.status from tblstudent s join tblresults r on s.studentcode=r.studentcode
```

Output i am getting

[image]

Now i want that if my status is 'promoted' checkbox get checked and if it is 'not promoted' checkbox gets unchecked.I dont want to use row databound method.Just want my work to be completed in the below lines

```
 sql = "select s.studentcode,s.studentname,r.status from tblstudent s join tblresults r on s.studentcode=r.studentcode";
    ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SchoolCode"].ToString());
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        grdstudents.DataSource = ds;
        grdstudents.DataBind();
        grdstudents.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        alertdiv.Visible = true;
        lblalertmsg.Visible = true;
        btnclose.Visible = true;
        lblalertmsg.Text = "No Record found";
    }
```

Solution

query

```
select s.studentcode,s.studentname,if(r.status='Promoted',true,false) as status from tblstudent s left join tblresults r on s.studentcode=r.studentcode where s.classcode='10000'

grdstudents.DataSource = ds;// note we binded to final table
grdstudents.DataBind();
```

Checkbox field in aspx page inside gridview:

```
<ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkapply" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("status"))%>'/>
           </ItemTemplate>
```

This solution will help you to avoid extra code to be written while using itembinding or row data binding events of gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes can be checked/unchecked only using the boolean values. in this case because the Column: 'status' isn't representing boolean values, so directly binding data won't serve the purpose.

You need to follow two steps:

**Step 1.)** Copy the original Data to a new table and change the Data type of your 'status' column to Boolean.

**Step 2.)** Modify the data in status column in final table using Data of your original table.

Step 1:

```
ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SchoolCode"].ToString());
DataTable dtOriginalTable = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dtFinalTable = new DataTable();
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtOriginalTable.Columns)
{
dtFinalTable.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName);
}
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtFinalTable.Columns)
{
           if (dc.ColumnName == "status")
               dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
}
```

**Step 2 below::**

```
foreach (DataRow drow in dtOriginalTable.Rows)
{
         if( drow["status"].ToString().Equals("Promoted"))
              drow["status"]="true";
         else
              drow["status"]="false"
// ADD the row to final table 
dtFinalTable.Rows.Add(drow.ItemArray);
}
```

Now do your binding to GridView as:

```
grdstudents.DataSource = dtFinalTable ;// note we binded to final table
grdstudents.DataBind();
```

**NOTE::** Why step 1 is required? Because you cannot change the datatype of a column once it is populated with data.

***Also it will be a performance issue when the Database has a large number of data.***

Comment: but how the checkbox will bind to the status field.<ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkapply" runat="server"/>
               </ItemTemplate>

Comment: you should use the "Checked" property as : <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chkapply" Checked='<%#Bind("Column_Name_Here") %>' runat="server" /></ItemTemplate> OR try also : Checked='<%#  Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Column_Name_Here"))%>'

Answer (score 2):

You need to use OnItemDataBoundEvent for the grid.
If you dont want to use that event. Then you can loop through all the rows of the gridview.

If your grid id is `grid1` then loop through all the rows in `grid1.Rows`.
You will have to find you checkbox in row and then check/uncheck it based on you data.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid1.Rows)
{
   CheckBox checkBox1 = row.FindControl("checkBox1") as CheckBox;
   checkBox1.Checked = true; // based on condition

}
```

Comment: but i don't want to use any event.Is it possible to do it directly